# Direct link to Outlook webmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, webmail

Is there a link that

- opens the Microsoft Account login screen (where you can immediately start typing your email address), and
- after entering the password and answering whether you want to stay signed in, opens the Outlook webmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link for that would be:
[**https://outlook.office365.com/mail/**](https://outlook.office365.com/mail/)

This will open the Outlook webmail interface, and if not signed in it will ask you right on the page to sign in and then redirect you to the Outlook webmail interface.

Comment: @Dr.Gut， The link(https://outlook.office365.com/mail/) shared by Yisroel worked for me as well. You can open the browser in private mode and try it again.

Answer (score -1):

Unsure if this will work for you as well but the below works on several machines for me for what you are asking.

Grab the link immediately after clicking the sign in button on this page

https://outlook.live.com/owa/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will show a page with information about Outlook and "an option" to press to Sign in. What he asked was for a "direct link" to the sign-in page that will bring him to the Outlook webmail.